# Oracle ADF Form Submit Error

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-adf

I have created a form to insert data into `Expenses` table. when i'm trying to insert data i got below error.

```
Attribute ExpensesId in AppModule.ExpensesView1 is required.
```

I have a `Before Insert Trigger` to insert `ExpensesId` to the table. so i don't need to add `ExpensesId` manually.

how could i resolve this error ?

Answer (score 1):

in this case set the ADF BC type of the expenseId attribute to DBSequence so the framework knows that this is taken care of

Frank